# Python explode strings with comma and quotes

Tags: python, pandas, explode

I have a dataset with the following setup:

```
id   string_to_parse
1    "a","b"
2   "a,b","c"  
3   "c"
```

I need to get it into this

```
id   string_to_parse
1    a
1    b
2    a,b
2    c
3    c
```

I tried with

```
exploded_ = df['string_to_parse'].map(lambda x:x\
    .replace('"','')\
    .split(",")).explode()
```

Besides being very slow, it also misses the `"a,b"` and splits them also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and last [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['string_to_parse'] = df['string_to_parse'].str.strip('"').str.split('","')
df  = df.explode('string_to_parse')
print (df)
   id string_to_parse
0   1               a
0   1               b
1   2             a,b
1   2               c
2   3               c
```